# Webpack 4 and Babel 7 "import" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've been trying to set up Webpack 4 and Babel 7 to work with ES6 "import" in React. I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" at "import React from 'react';" in Chrome 71. It worked in Webpack 3 and Babel 6, so I think I'm doing something wrong with the Babel setup.

These are my dev dependencies:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.6",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
"webpack": "^4.26.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
```

My .babelrc looks like this:

```
{
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
"plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    ["@babel/syntax-dynamic-import"]
]
}
```

I've been trying babel.config.js as well, to no prevail.

My webpack-config.js file:

```
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    injext: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", __dirname + '/src/index.js'],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')
            },
        ]
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'transformed.js',
        path: __dirname + 'build'
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './src/',
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      port: 8000,
      publicPath: "/src/public",
      noInfo: false
    },
    plugins: [
        HTMLWebpackPluginConfig,
        new ExtractTextPlugin('public/css/style.css', {
            allChunks: true
        }),

        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production')
        }),
    ]}
```

Comment: Is Webpack actually bundling anything? Can you show the compiled script that is getting read by the browser?

Comment: I think I stumbled upon same problem last year, I downgraded my webpack to `"webpack": "3.10.0",`. Lets see if that helps. Also my `.babelrc` use `"presets": ["react"]`. Im not sure about `babel/preset-react`. Snip your `.webpack-config.js` file too, possibly missing something?

Comment: @SammyTaylor Thanks! I see there is no bundle, so that probably explains a lot. I will add my webpack config as an edit above. Please let me know if you need more info! Thanks

Comment: @NikkoKhresna Yeah, the babel/preset-react is babel v4 syntax. :) I really prefer not to go back to Webpack 3. I have added my webpack config as an edit above.

Comment: im sure this is not webpack4 syntax `injext: 'body'`? Although im not sure if thats where the problem is..lemme check again

Comment: Thanks, i will see if it changes anything.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change things, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i seemed to have fixed to issue after spitting through my webpack config. The issue was caused by this:

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: './src/',
  historyApiFallback: true,
  hot: true,
  port: 8000,
  publicPath: "/src/public",
  noInfo: false
},
```

I'll see if i can find what exactly causes Webpack not to bundle with this. Thanks for all the help anyway!